# modprobe Key was rejected by service when installing C++ library

Tags: c++, linux

I an trying to install a library in a computer running Ubuntu 22.04. When I run `make` I get this warning:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic/build M=/home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4 LDDINCDIR=/home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/../include modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/CAENUSBdrvB.o
  MODPOST /home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/CAENUSBdrvB.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/CAENUSBdrvB.ko
  BTF [M] /home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/CAENUSBdrvB.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /home/human/Downloads/CAENUSBdrvB-1.5.4/CAENUSBdrvB.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic'
```

Then, when I run `sudo make install` I get this error:

```
installing CAENUSBdrvB driver.. please wait
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'CAENUSBdrvB': Key was rejected by service
make: *** [Makefile:47: install] Error 1
```

I was able to install this library in a computer running Ubuntu 20.04 in the past.

Honestly I have no idea if this is a problem of the library itself, compatibility with Ubuntu 22.04, or what. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a library, it is a kernel module. The error produced is specific to the driver you built and we cannot help you with that.

Comment: `Key was rejected by service` means your module is incorrectly signed.

Comment: So this does not mean that I am doing something wrong but rather that what I want to install is wrong? (e.g. designed for an older version of Linux kernel)

Comment: Why would it not just mean what I said, which is that the module is not signed correctly for the kernel?